# Service discovery does not discover multiple nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I have elasticsearch cluster on kubernetes on aws. I have used upmc operator and readonlyrest security plugin.
I have started my cluster passing yaml to upmc operator with 3 data / master and ingest nodes.
However when I do /localhsot:9200/_nodes all I see only 1 node is being assigned. Service discovery did not attach other nodes to the clusters. Essentially I have a single node cluster. Any settings I am missing  or after creating cluster I need to run some settings so that all nodes become part of the cluster ?

Here is my yml file:
The following yaml file is used to create the cluster.
This yaml config creates 3 master/data/ingest nodes and upmcoperator uses pod afinity to allocate pods in different zones. 
All 9 nodes are getting created just fine, but they are unable to become part of the cluster.

```
====================================
apiVersion: enterprises.upmc.com/v1
kind: ElasticsearchCluster
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
spec:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana-oss:6.1.3
    image-pull-policy: Always
  cerebro:
    image: upmcenterprises/cerebro:0.7.2
    image-pull-policy: Always
  elastic-search-image: myelasticimage:elasticsearch-mod-v0.1
  elasticsearchEnv:
    - name: PUBLIC_KEY
      value: "default"
    - name: NETWORK_HOST
      value: "_eth0:ipv4_"
  image-pull-secrets:
    - name: egistrykey
  image-pull-policy: Always
  client-node-replicas: 3
  master-node-replicas: 3
  data-node-replicas: 3
  network-host: 0.0.0.0
  zones: []
  data-volume-size: 1Gi
  java-options: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  snapshot:
    scheduler-enabled: false
    bucket-name: somebucket
    cron-schedule: "@every 1m"
    image: upmcenterprises/elasticsearch-cron:0.0.4
  storage:
    type: standard
    storage-class-provisioner: volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/storage-class
    volume-reclaim-policy: Delete
```

Comment: Please add your yamls.

Comment: added my yaml file